# How to take a textfield on a custom view

Tags: cocoa-touch

I want to take a textfield on a view. The code of that view is

```
            if (indexPath.row==0) {
            UIView *viewshow=[[[UIView alloc]init]autorelease];
            viewshow.frame = CGRectMake(5, 60, 310, 230);
            viewshow.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            [cell addSubview:viewshow];
```

}

And a take a custom text field by this code

```
            if (indexPath.row==0) {
            UIView *viewshow=[[[UIView alloc]init]autorelease];
            viewshow.frame = CGRectMake(5, 60, 310, 230);
            viewshow.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            [cell addSubview:viewshow];
            UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 30, 200)];
            textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
            textField.placeholder = @"Enter the Text";
            textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0];
            textField.delegate = self;
            //cell.accessoryView = textField;
            [viewshow addSubview:textField];
         }
```

Now the textfield is coming in the vertical direction not in the horizontal direction in the view.Now i dont understand what exactly i need to do to sort out this problem.
Please help.....

Comment: This question is not related to Xcode.

Comment: Is your problem get solved?

Comment: Yes my problem has been solved.as i was taking wrong frame in my coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the frame width and height of `uitextfield` ie,

```
 UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 200, 30)];
```